# How can I make my markerclusters show an average value instead of the number of samples in a cluster

Tags: r, leaflet, markerclusterer, palette

I'm doing research into water quality along some beaches and I have repeatedly been taking samples on set locations. I am now trying to make an interactive map that shows my results but keep running into this issue.

My current code is:

```
    #create range to define the type as follows 
CountsLoc$CFU_Range = cut(CountsLoc$CFU_TOTAL, 
                       breaks = c(0, 20, 35, 50, 1000 ), right=FALSE,
                       labels = c("Good[0-20)", "Moderate[20-35)", "Problematic[35-50)", "bad[50-400)"))

#Define a color palette corresponding to the magnitude ranges
pal = colorFactor(palette = c("Green","yellow", "orange", "red"), domain=CountsLoc$CFU_Range)

# Create the map object & add circle marker
leaflet(data=CountsLoc) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Lon, 
                   lat= ~Lat, 
                   color = ~ pal(CFU_Range),popup = ~CountsLoc$CFU_TOTAL, #use the palette
                   label = paste("Magnitude=", CountsLoc$CFU_TOTAL, "Type=", CountsLoc$CFU_Range), 
                   clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(showCoverageOnHover = TRUE,
                                                         zoomToBoundsOnClick = TRUE,
                                                         spiderfyOnMaxZoom = TRUE,
                                                         removeOutsideVisibleBounds = TRUE,
                                                         spiderLegPolylineOptions = list(weight = 1.5, color = "#222", 
                                                                                         opacity = 0.5)))
```

This is now giving me markers that are colored and numbered based on the amount of samples that have been taken from a location instead of the average CFU(contamination) found on a location. Anyone knows how to customize this? thanks for reading